# How to remove background color of TextField on Flutter Widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

I can't remove the shadow and the background of the TextField, here is my code:

```
TextFormField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(),
                            validator: (input) =>
                                input == "" ? 'The task is empty' : null,
                            onSaved: (input) => task = input,
                          )
```

this is the result that I want

[image]

I always try BoxDecoration but no success because don't is compatible with TextFormField.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You should set filled to true.

```
TextField(decoration: InputDecoration( fillColor: Colors.red, filled: true)),
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your `TextFormField` inside a `Container` and change its `color` property to match your background color (as from your picture I'll assume its `white`):

```
     Container(
        color: Colors.white, // or any color that matches your background
        child: TextFormField(
                 decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(),
                 validator: (input) => input == "" ? 'The task is empty' : null,
                 onSaved: (input) => task = input,
               )
     ),
```

Comment: Don't works, I need to remove the text field details, like the borders, the shadow box.